# How to model the mixing of two fluids?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulations, turbulence

In the context of a research project of mine, I am faced with the difficult task of modeling the mixing of two fluids in a container. I would like to achieve the following:

Given a **container** (cylindrical or spherical) containing a **static mixture of gases** (carbon dioxide + nitrogen), an **inflow channel of oxygen** into the container, and a **vacuum outflow** exiting the container, I would like to **simulate the evolution of the mixing of gases inside the container (composition and vortices) and in the outflow channel**. In fact, the goal is to end up with a crude model of a lung with the particularity of a vacuum outflow.

Does anyone point me to a tool (perferably free) or a set of techniques that could help me build such a simulation? I can program in pretty much any language, and GUI software packages would be ok too.

Comment: "I can program in pretty much any language" ... even [COBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL), [MUMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS), [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29) and [malbolge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge)? (that aside, there are thounsands of programming languages, plus all the private languages used internally by corporations, plus all the languages developed for the educational value of creating a programming language, ...). No one even knows about the existence of more than a fraction of all programming languages.

Comment: Starting from a cylindrical or spherical container to model mixing is lungs seems the wrong starting point: lungs aren't 'continuous' containers, rather they're made up of huge amounts of Alveoli. The constant partitioning of flows already provides an excellent mechanism for mixing.

Comment: @SebastianRiese: I think most people say "in any [programming] language" and imply it to mean *common* languages (python, C, C++, Fortran, Java), rather than *all* languages.

Comment: @Raoul: You will want to look up what's called *two fluid flows*

Comment: @SebastianRiese What I meant is: there are several common languages I do know. The rest I can learn if necessary to code this simulation. Yes, even COBOL, although MUMPS would definitely be more adapted to my field.

Comment: @Gert Yes, I do understand that. Of course, it would be great to be able to model the whole respiratory system. Unfortunately, I think that would deserve a whole PhD to make it work. Fortunately, I am more interested in what happens locally in the main bronchi, making my model not totally off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the need to resolve the vortical structure and instantaneous composition (at least, that's what it sounds like you need to do from your question), you're going to need a full fluid dynamics solver. Your best bet in this case would be to use [OpenFOAM](http://openfoam.com/).

It is a full-fledged CFD solver that could do (or be extended to do) virtually any problem that comes up in computational fluids. There's a bit of a learning curve, but that's true of any code and at least this one has a large user-base and community support.

Comment: If mixing weren't involved, I might have suggested [Elmer](https://www.csc.fi/web/elmer), but I'm pretty sure it can't handle it.

Comment: @KyleKanos It looks like it has some advection-reaction capabilities, but only for a single scalar -- in this case, that could work because there's only 2 fluids mixing and so you only need a single reactant scalar depending on the implementation. The part I don't like though is the boundary conditions -- it doesn't have the characteristic boundary conditions that are important for proper modeling of subsonic flows (see [Yoo and Im](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13647830600898995) or [Poinsot and Lele](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999192900462)).

Comment: I've always kinda viewed Elmer as a "we've built the framework, you do the rest" type of freeware code, rather than "all you need to do is specify the problem" that OpenFOAM takes.

Comment: @KyleKanos I'd never heard of it until now, but I'm going through the documentation and it looks pretty useful.

Comment: It was on the Ubuntu repos at one point (and still is for Linux Mint, so it may still be for Ubuntu as well); I recall it taking a bit of work for me to get it do something somewhat trivial (like a flow down a channel)